# Do I need to remove an observer from the NSNotificationCenter once, or as many times as it was added?

Tags: iphone, nsnotificationcenter

in my `viewDidLoad`, I add my controller as an observer for two notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:NetworkStatusChangedNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkLocationStatus:) name:LocationStatusChangedNotification object:nil];
```

in my `dealloc`, should I remove it once, or twice?  The removeObserver method doesn't seem to specify a particular notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]; // is this required?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove it only once.

If you need it, you can also use `-removeObserver:name:object:` to stop observing just one of the notifications.

Comment: You can also remove the observer for a particular notification and/or object using the `removeObserver:name:object:`. This will keep the observer in the notification centre if it is observing other notifications.

Comment: @Jasarien I think you added the comment and I edited my answer to say the same thing at the same time :)

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the best way to clear your doubts:

```
The following example illustrates how to unregister someObserver for all 
notifications for which it had previously registered:

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:someObserver];
```

Answer (score 1):

From Reference:

> RemoveObserver:
>   Removes all the entries specifying a given observer from the receiver’s dispatch table.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

so you need to call  it only once